# Question about the Foldable Maybe instance

Tags: haskell, fold

Source: Hutton, Graham. "*Programming in Haskell*" (p. 267)

> 3. Show how the Maybe type can be made foldable and traversable, by giving explicit definitions for fold, foldMap, foldr, foldl and traverse.

I did `foldr` definition. For the purposes of checking my solution, I found online this code:

```
 -- foldr :: (a -> b -> b) -> b -> Maybe a -> b
    foldr _ _ Nothing = mempty
    foldr f v (Just a) = f a v
```

It seems the acumulator should be returned in the base case (instead of `mempty`). Is that right ?

Comment: `mempty`  looks like a stowaway from a `foldMap` definition, since `foldMap :: Monoid m => (a -> m) -> Maybe a -> m`.

Comment: The easiest way to define these is to consider the `[]` instance and to identify `Nothing` with `[]` and `Just a` with `[a]`.

Comment: Thank you for your suggestion, @chepner. You said: "identify `Just a` with `[a]`. The `[]` instance doesn't have `[a]` case. I hope you can clarify since I am surely missing your point.

Comment: It knows how to handle arbitrary non-empty lists; `[a]` is a non-empty list.

Comment: `fmap f (x:xs) == f x : fmap f xs`, so in the case of a singleton list, `fmap f [x] == f x : fmap f [] == f x : [] == [f x]`.

Comment: Thank you, @chepner !

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Yes, the code you're looking at is bogus and won't even compile. It should do what you said:

```
foldr _ v Nothing = v
```

---

Note that you don't really need to do all this manual work, except as an exercise. You could just write

```hs
{-# language DeriveTraversable #-}
module MyModule where
import Prelude hiding (Maybe (..))
data Maybe a = Nothing | Just a
  deriving (Show, Eq, Ord, Functor, Foldable, Traversable)
```

and be done with it. If you don't want to rely on a language extension, then you still only have to write one method: `traverse`. You can write

```hs
import Prelude hiding (Maybe (..))
import Data.Traversable

data Maybe a = Nothing | Just a deriving (Show, Eq)

instance Foldable Maybe where
  foldMap = foldMapDefault
instance Functor Maybe where
  fmap = fmapDefault
instance Traversable Maybe where
  traverse _ Nothing = _1 -- fill in the blanks
  traverse f (Just a) = _2
```

In the case of `Maybe`, this should produce optimal definitions of all the class methods. For some types, you'll need to write some methods by hand to get optimal results. For example, the default generally won't give a good definition of `<$` for recursive types.

Comment: Yeah I feel like relying on the deriving mechanism is definitely cheating.  But only defining `traverse` is the way to go except perhaps to practice.

Comment: @luqui, yes, although like I said some types really want certain methods optimized, most often `<$`, `null`, and/or `length`.

Comment: Thank you. I did the homework. Is it correct ? 
```instance Traversable Maybe where
  traverse _ Nothing = pure Nothing
  traverse f (Just a) = Just <$> (f a)```

Comment: @F.Zer, yup, that's the one!

Comment: @F.Zer: Since the comment box here doesn’t show newlines+indents, it’s helpful to use `{` `;` `}` explicitly so that the code is valid Haskell: `instance Traversable Maybe where { traverse _ Nothing = pure Nothing; traverse f (Just a) = Just <$> f a }`. Then people can simply copy & paste to test your work, and in general it’s easier to read.

Comment: Thank you, @Jon Purdy !